# Firefox setting to enable cross domain Ajax request

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I need to *temporally* allow cross domain XMLHttpRequest. Changing firefox security setting seems to be the way to go. But I've tried with [this](http://blog.dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html) and [this](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2007/08/30/cross-domain-xhr-with-firefox/) but they didnt work. Has anyone been able to configure this before? Thanks.

Comment: If you can require changing the Firefox security settings couldn't you use a GreaseMonkey script?

Comment: Try it on Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: Try out my Firefox add on to enable cross domain with ajax here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For modern browsers, you may try the following approach:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

In short, you need to add the following into the `SERVER` response header (the following allows access *from* `foo.example`):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

Note that the `X-PINGOTHER` is the custom header that is inserted by JavaScript, and should differ from site to site.

If you want any site access your server in Ajax, use `*` instead.

---

Edit:

When I first answered the question by **2009**, I actually hit the same problem, and I worked around it using the server side config.

There was no plugin on FF or Chrome by then.

However, now we do have alternatives using the browser side plugin, please check the answer of `tsds`

Comment: if I understand correctly, this does not solve the original problem if you can not change the server

Comment: Note that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` will not work if you would also like to use XHR's `withCredentials` option to send cookie headers along. You do need to specify a specific domain in that case.

Comment: -1 It doesnt answer the question. The OP ask for browser side config

Answer (score 27):

If you just don't want to waste your time on cross-domain issues during development and testing of your app you can use addon [Force CORS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/) for FF.

UPDATE: It seems that this addon no longer exists. But there is another option - this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Comment: Forcecors is great. Worth mentioning that after installing you have to click view => toolbars => add-on bar. Then the cors button will show in the right bottom click on that to enable it. I unzipped the xpi and see there is a toggle function when a button was pushed but never see the button.

Comment: "Worth mentioning that after installing you have to click view => toolbars => add-on bar."
You, sir, are a saint

Comment: It seems FF has removed it.

Comment: Also Google will start phasing out third-party cookies from Q1 2024 : https://www.techcircle.in/2023/05/19/google-will-start-phasing-out-third-party-cookies-from-q1-2024

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried using jQuery's [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) request? As of version 1.3 jQuery supports certain types of cross domain ajax requests.

Quoting from the reference above:

> Note: All remote (not on the same
>   domain) requests should be specified
>   as GET when 'script' or 'jsonp' is the
>   dataType (because it loads script
>   using a DOM script tag). Ajax options
>   that require an XMLHttpRequest object
>   are not available for these requests.
>   The complete and success functions are
>   called on completion, but do not
>   receive an XHR object; the beforeSend
>   and dataFilter functions are not
>   called.
>
> As of jQuery 1.2, you can load JSON
>   data located on another domain if you
>   specify a JSONP callback, which can be
>   done like so: "myurl?callback=?".
>   jQuery automatically replaces the ?
>   with the correct method name to call,
>   calling your specified callback. Or,
>   if you set the dataType to "jsonp" a
>   callback will be automatically added
>   to your Ajax request.

Comment: we are using this to retrieve json data, but this is html that gets incorporated in the page and it's only temporal, so changing firefox config should be the simplest thing to do

Comment: Why the downvote?  Using a framework's cross domain capabilities is a reasonable response to this question.  The fact that HTML was required wasn't mentioned in the question, just in the comment to my response.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the thing, there is no way to "temporarily" disable cross-domain XMLHttpRequest, if you can disable it temporarily then it can be disabled permanently.  This is a rather common problem in the modern-day of AJAX programming and is most often solved using the technique known as cross-domain scripting.

The idea here being is that if you call out to a cross-domain script it returns JavaScript (JSON) results that are then passed on to a function on your end.

Here is some sample code to illustrate how it may look from a JavaScript code perspective:

```
  function request_some_data() {
    var s = "http://my.document.url.com/my_data?p1=v1&p2=v2&callback=myfunc";

      try {
        try{
          document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+s+"'></scr"+"ipt>");
        } 
        catch(e){
          var x = document.createElement("script");
          x.src = s;
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
        }
      }
      catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
      }
   }
```

You will then define a function in your code that receives the data and in the server you "handle" the callback case, here is the client-side JavaScript:

```
function myfunc(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

And on the server side, here i'm giving a PHP example but this can be done just as easily in Java or what-ever your server-side technology is:

```
<?php
   if($_GET["callback"]) {
     print($_GET["callback"] . "(");
   }
   /* place your JSON object code/logic here */
   if($_GET["callback"]) {
     print(");");
   }
 ?>
```

Note that what you are generating on the server side winds up being some JavaScript that gets executed on the client side.

Comment: `"<scr"+"ipt"` this looks so malicious

Comment: Of course you can disable it temporarily. For example, start Chrome with --disable-web-security.

Comment: @JosephLust please note this was asked / answered a bit before Chrom had widespread use.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried using that 'UniversalBrowswerRead' thing too and it didn't work. You might be able to add an 'allow' header, but I haven't actually tried doing it yet. It's pretty new.

You can find more information [here](http://websecurity.ro/blog/2008/04/10/cross-domain-requests-will-be-back/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing this from `file://`. I'd like to send queries to two servers from a local HTML file (a testbed).

This particular case should not be any safety concern, but only Safari allows this.

Here is the [best discussion](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/) I've found of the issue.

Comment: Thanks ! I guess I wont be testing in Chrome no more.

Answer (score 1):

What about using something like mod_proxy? Then it looks to your browser like the requests are going to the same server, but they're really being forwarded to another server.

Answer (score 1):

I used Fiddler as a proxy. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) redirects localhost calls to a external server.

I configured Firefox to use manual proxy (127.0.0.1 port 8888). Fiddler capture the calls and redirect them to another server, by using URL filters.

Answer (score 1):

To allow cross domain:

1. enter `about:config`
2. accept to be careful
3. enter `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` in the search bar
4. change to false

You can now close the tab. Normally you can now make cross domain request with this config.

See [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my add on for firefox. It allows to cross domain in the lastest firefox version: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/

Answer (score -1):

Manually editing firefox's settings is the way to go, but it's inconvenient when you need to do it often.

Instead, you can install an add-on that will do it for you in one click.

I use `CORS everywhere`, which works great for me.

Here is [a link to the installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)

Comment: Answers that just links to other resources are generally considered bad, as they can change in time. Please add the most relevant part in the answer itself.